# Why aren't my custom JavaScripts firing consistently despite enqueuing in the footer of a WordPress site?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, if-statement, wp-enqueue-scripts

I have multiple JavaScript scripts in separate files which must be fired on different pages. They are executed in the footer using `wp_enqueue_script()`. They work, but not consistently. I even added `setTimeout` to make sure they load last as they have to fill up some fields in the `body`. Why is it not firing sometimes?

Is there anything wrong here?

```
// passenger elevators
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'passen_elev_custom_js');

function passen_elev_custom_js() {
  if( is_page( 4744 ) ) {
    wp_enqueue_script('passenger-elevators', 'https://mywebsite.com/passenger-elevators.js',
    array(), false, true);
  }
}

// home elevators
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'home_elev_custom_js');

function home_elev_custom_js() {
  if( is_page( 5231 ) ) {
    wp_enqueue_script('home-elevators', 'https://mywebsite.com/home-elevators.js',
    array(), false, true);
  }
}

// observation elevators
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'obs_elev_custom_js');

function obs_elev_custom_js() {
  if( is_page( 5343 ) ) {
    wp_enqueue_script('observation-elevators', 'https://mywebsite.com/observation-elevators.js',
    array(), false, true);
  }
}
```

Comment: For one thing. This can all be in one function. You're also not declaring any dependencies. Is jQuery required?

Comment: @HowardE There are no dependencies in my scripts. But I will declare them if I add any `jQueries` in the future. Thanks  for pointing it out. Can you give a little more explanation on how to place them all in one function? I am still new to JS.

Comment: This is PHP code. Just put all if conditions in one function.